# Send JMS from Jboss 4.2.3GA to 7.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jndi

I'm trying to send a JMS message (remotely) from Jboss 4.2.3GA instance to Jboss 7.1.1.Final instance. When I try to do it "7.1.1 style"

```
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

I got

> ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

When I try to do it "4.2.3" way

```
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

I got

> UnknownHostException: remote

With different address (jnp://127.0.0.1:4447) I have `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000000C`

I'm starting the 7.1.1 with `standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0`.
Please help cause I'm stepping blindfolded here. Any example on how to send a JMS from 4.2.3GA to 7.1.1 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with this issue lays in the fact that

> The old jnp based JNDI implementation used in previous JBoss versions is no longer supported

We have to use `remote:` protocol. Useful resources are [jboss dev guide JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference) and [master the jboss ejb tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial).

They tell you that you need `jboss-client.jar` from `%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/client`. This is indeed true for Java SE project. With different app server it is too much cause it results in some `javax.*` conflicts and causes my injection points to fail. I ended up with this set up of jars:

- jboss-remoting-3.2.3.GA.jar
- jboss-remote-naming-1.0.2.Final.jar
- jboss-sasl-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jboss-marshalling-1.3.11.GA.jar
- jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.11.GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
- netty-3.2.6.Final.jar
- xnio-api-3.0.3.GA.jar
- xnio-nio-3.0.3.GA.jar
- hornetq-core-client-2.2.13.Final.jar
- hornetq-jms-client-2.2.13.Final.jar

And successfully send a message to Jboss 7.1.1 test topic:

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
Topic topic = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup("jms/topic/test");
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = cf.createConnection();
    Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello world");
    producer.send(message);
} catch (JMSException e) {
    log.error(e);
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However I had to turn off security because of

> javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed

I didn't figure out how to authenticate. I add user with `add-user` script and play with different properties without success. You can turn off security by removing `security-realm="ApplicationRealm"` from this section in `standalone-full.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
    <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

and deselectiong Profile>Messaging>Messaging Provider>Security enabled? in Jboss server administration console.

**UPDATE**
Disabling security is not necessary. Use this options:

```
env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass");
```